# Can I use code to check if the receiver of airdrop has an application installed?

Tags: ios

I share the .zip file with airdrop via UIActivityViewController in my app.

```
@IBAction func shareAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let newFileURL = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/test.zip"
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: newFileURL)
    let shareItems = [url] as [Any]


    let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems as [Any], applicationActivities: [])
    ac.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList]


    if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) {
        let popover = ac.popoverPresentationController
        popover?.sourceView = shareButton
        popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 40, width: 0, height: 0)
    }
    present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

    func completionHandler(activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, shared: Bool, items: [Any]?, error: Error?) {
        if (shared) {
            print("Share Succeed!")
        }
        else {
            print("Share failed!")
        }
    }
    ac.completionWithItemsHandler = completionHandler
}
```

I would like to know:
What application did the receiver use to open the file I sent? / Does the receiver have my app installed?
Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
If you want to make sure the file is opened with your app only, you need to assign a unique file extension and make your app handle that extension.
You can still use the zip format internally.

Comment: Thanks in advance.

I have renamed the received ".zip file" in the application and processed the unique file extension (example: fileName.zip-> fileName.myAppUseZip Extension) with my application, but when the device does not install my application, the system pops up:

"'fileName'would like to share a file that requires an app from the App Store." There are three options attached:

1. Get App 2. Save to iCloud Drive 3. Cancel

The new question is: Can I set up the app store download interface to jump to my app when I click Get App?

Comment: @user10877689: I don't know. I suggest you create a new question on this topic.